# Unpack Boolean from Firebase database snapshot?

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Good evening!

I am attempting to retrieve a Boolean value from firebase in my swift iOS app, but I have run into a silly issue. Unpacking strings from my snapshots is working great, but Bools are another story... I am clearly missing something (hopfully) simple. Here is the code:

```
for child in snapshot.children{

    let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
    let shouldBeBool = (child as AnyObject).value as Bool
    ...
    // Do Stuff with the values
}
```

I am getting a "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error on the Let shouldBeBool line.

The code will compile if I change the "as Bool" to "as String", but the app crashes as expected once it attempts to read the Boolean value in the snapshot as a string.

I have also tried this and get the same error:

```
for child in snapshot.children{

    let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
    var shouldBeBool: Bool
    shouldBeBool = (child as AnyObject).value as! Bool
    ...
    // Do Stuff with the values
}
```

I do not understand how force unwrapping it as a Boolean is ambiguous. Does swift have different types of Boolean?

Hopefully I am just missing something silly.

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE** The accepted answer worked (Thank you!), with one additional modification. Working code below.

```
for child in snapshot.children{

    let key = (child as AnyObject).key as String
    let b = (child as! DataSnapshot).value as! NSNumber // Note the double force unwrapping... bad practice?
    let shouldBeBool = Bool(truncating: b)
    ...
    // Do Stuff with shouldBeBool as a boolean and key as a string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#value), one of the concrete types returned is `NSNumber` and there's a note that it includes booleans, so you need to cast `shouldBeBool` to `NSNumber` then use `Bool`'s `init(truncating:)` to convert the `NSNumber` to a `Bool`.

```swift
let number = (child as AnyObject).value as NSNumber
let shouldBeBool = Bool(truncating: number) // false if 0, true otherwise
```

Comment: I'm guessing firebase always internally store booleans as `NSNumber`. I haven't checked this code my self.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this still draws an a "Ambiguous use of value" error on the "let number =..." line. However, I am intrigued that this could be a firebase specific issue. I assumed it was swift (as inferred in my question) since I do not have this problem working with firebase for android. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Try to remove the cast to `AnyObject`. I don't think it's really necessary since Swift can infer the type for you. Also, in Swift the type of `value` is `Any?` so there is a chance it could be `nil`. so the line would be `let number = child.value as? NSNumber`. Then, you would need to unwrap the optional. If you try this and the warning message goes away, I will update my answer.